Optimizing a function with linear constraints containing a singular matrix, in Python
I'm working with traffic data to try the reconstruct the origin-destination matrix of a region, based on the article Bell1983.
Basically, for each pair of locations, we need to get how many vehicles (/passengers) go from one place to the other, and we have data of public road traffic for it. This would be the O-D matrix. It's stored in the odm vector (flattened) with length M, the daily traffic for each road is stored in vector v with length N, and an extra matrix P, describing the probability of going through a certain road when going from place A to place B, stored in array P of size N x M (this matrix is constructed by some simple heuristic). In my case, there are 31 roads and 120 pairs of locations (16 choose 2). The goal is the same as in the article: given constraints of the relation of these variables, get the solution that minimizes a function f. In practicality, another important thing to note that constraint always contains singular matrix. (In the article they actually derive a general procedure for finding the solution, but for now I'm trying to write code to get a solution for any objective function.)
Models have the constraint v = P * odm so we have M equations for the M variables. The problem is, in practical cases, P will be underdetermined because of things like 3 places laying on the same line (e.g. connected by 2 roads only, you have only 2 independent equations for 3 place pair values) thus P won't have an inverse. Same in my case, P has 28 independent equations only instead of 31. For this reason there are many possible solutions to the equation. Classical methods introduce some function and choose the solution minimizing this function - such a function is typically maximizing entropy (== minimizing (-1)*entropy).
Using Python, I've tried scipy.optimize.minimize with a simple function to minimize, given the constraint, but got the message: Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem. I know, that P is singular and that caused this problem, but P will always be singular, underdetermined, I can only work with it. The code:
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds

#Objective function
def f(odm):
    #Entropy maximizing (== minimizing the negative entropy)
    return np.sum(odm * np.log(odm))

#Constraint(s)
def constraint_eq(odm):
    return P @ odm - v
constraints = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_eq}

bounds = Bounds(1e-5, np.inf) #positive values for log
res = minimize(f, odm, constraints=constraints, bounds=bounds)
optimal_odm = res.x

There will always be multiple solutions (and it is guaranteed that there will be at least one solution) and if the solution space is given it should be easy to find the one minimizing f.
How can I run an optimization that allows for singular matrices in constraint? Do I need to use a different solver method?
I know one possibility is to just exclude 3 equations to have a non-singular P matrix for optimization, then after having the optimal solution, solving the remaining equations, but this seems like quite some hussle.
(Solutions for MATLAB would also be useful, I'm familiar with it to some extent.)
For reproducing the problem, the road vector would be v = np.array([11479, 24663, 39783, 26064, 65054, 52134, 45172, 18807, 6386, 6544, 23218, 36905, 16558, 5385, 4562, 38232, 8263, 13132, 22395, 3759, 3910, 4100, 17482, 7736, 14255, 5154, 9436, 6554, 11623, 10747, 13110]) 
and the P-matrix stored as a CSV can be found here: GitHub.

It's not just that the matrix is singular - some of your constraints are unsatisfiable. For example, P[24] is all zero, but v[24] is not zero. That constraint can't be satisfied no matter what. If I drop #24 and #26, the singularity problem goes away, but the constraints are still unsatisfiable. I tried plugging these constraints into cvxpy, and there is no solution that respects both the bounds and constraints of this problem.

@Nick ODell Thank you very much! Well, that's interesting. That must be a P-matrix design issue, there shouldn't be any rows with only zeros. I'll look into correcting P. I'm wondering if there are any "fast" methods of debugging this issue but for now I will just collect the linearly independent equations and the groups of linearly dependent equations. If there will indeed be satisfiable solutions, and no all-zero rows, should scipy.optimize.minimize work?

One way to troubleshoot this is to look at the matrix rank. For a 31 row matrix, it should be 31, or your constraints will be singular. To find which row causes problems, you can test subsets of your matrix. E.g. matrix_rank(P[:1]) == 1 tests the rank of the first row, matrix_rank(P[:2]) == 2 tests the rank of the first two rows together. Some rows will not be problematic by themselves, but will become problematic when combined with another row. e.g. rows 11 and 26 in your example are duplicates.

"If there will indeed be satisfiable solutions, and no all-zero rows, should scipy.optimize.minimize work?" Yes, this looks reasonable. One thing I will point out is that you're using a non-linear constraint, which is slow, because the optimizer must evaluate the constraint everywhere. scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint is faster, because it can quickly find the subspace where the constraint is satisfied. So you can make it faster by rewriting it as LinearConstraint(P, ub=v, lb=v). You'll still need solve the singularity problem, though.

That's an interesting insight, I did not know it handles the constraint nonlinearly! Thank you!

Another speed tip is to give it an explicit gradient with minimize(..., jac=fprime) argument. WolframAlpha says the derivative here is def fprime(x): return np.log(x) + 1, and checking with scipy.optimize.check_grad(), that seems to be approximately correct, for positive values at least. This will save N function evaluations per iteration versus doing it numerically, where N is the number of dimensions of your problem, so it's helpful with high dimensions.

A way to attack the singularity problem from another direction is method='trust-constr'. It seems to have an optimization algorithm which can cope with constraints being singular. This solver is often more reliable than SLSQP, but it's also slower.

Thank you very much, looking into these right now.

Try a different solver. This is a quirk of SLSQP; other NLP solvers don't have a problem with these types of singularities. Note that SCIPY is only for small dense problems. For larger, sparse problems, I would look at other solvers (e.g. IPOPT).
